# Automatically find value and move to a second column, Google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to move the station/unit identifiers using Google App Script from column B to Column D. This step is a small part of this whole process I have so I can eliminate excess data on this sheet that is emailed to me every day. I have a script that finds and gets the station/unit identifiers, but then it fills up the data and writes everyone it has found. So instead of just moving the one, it will initially do it correctly, but then it will write two of them, then three, then four, and so on deleting all the names. How do I get it to do this just one at a time?

```
function copyrange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Smd4fQ1nG_O7wXlcTzEqeZw9ghdcB_keqEy0d-CBVFM")
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Roster Report'); 
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('B:B');
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == 'Rank') {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+2,1,1,2).getValues());
  j.push(i);
  Logger.log(i)
 
 sheet.getRange(i+1,3,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
 }

}
}
```

Here is the sheet:
[Roster Report](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Smd4fQ1nG_O7wXlcTzEqeZw9ghdcB_keqEy0d-CBVFM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, you are trying to copy the `Rank` names from Column `B` into the adjacent cell in Column `D` as shown below.

> [image]

However, if there is any misunderstanding, please clarify your goal by updating your question to provide more clarity.

## SUGGESTION

Instead of using a for loop & manually setting the values for each range of cells in each iteration, you can try using the `map()` & `filter()` methods to manipulate your current sheet data. This approach allows you to change only the values that need to be changed and retrieve only the column that requires modification in a single run. Here is an example of a tweaked script that provides more context:

## Script

```
function copyrange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Smd4fQ1nG_O7wXlcTzEqeZw9ghdcB_keqEy0d-CBVFM').getSheetByName('Roster Report');
  var sheetValues = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //Produce initial result
  var initialResult = sheetValues.map((row, index) =>
    row[1] == 'Rank' ? //Checks if 'Rank' cell is found in a row
      row.map(column => column == 'Name' ? //If 'true', find the 'Name' 
        sheetValues[index + 1][1] //Alter the current value that has the same index as the 'Name' with the value after the row that has the same index as the 'Rank'.
      : column) //if 'Name' is not found (false), do not alter the value
    : row); //if 'Rank' is not found (false), do not alter the value
  
  //Filter the values and only return the values for Column 'D'.
  var result = initialResult.map(data => data.map((x, i) => i == 3 ? x.trim()+' ' : null).filter(x => x) );

  //Set the values in Column 'D'.
  sheet.getRange(`D1:D${result.length}`).setValues(result);
}
```

## Demo

> After running the script

[image]

## Reference

- [map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly and thank you fo the explanation!